# Non-html methods Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

There is a Spring MVC app. I need to track Put, Patch and Delete form methods. I use java configuration, so there is that file instead of web.xml:

```
public class DispatcherServletInializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
       return new Class[]{Config.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
       return new String[]{"/"};
   }

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
       super.onStartup(aServletContext);
       registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
   }

   private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
       aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
              new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
   }
}
```

Last method registers HiddenHttpMethodFilter.
So where is the problem? There are 2 pages: index.html and show.hmtl. First page is shown when URL is "/files". Second page is shown when URL is "/files/{id}". Non-html methods work perfect on the first page, but absolutely don't work on the second one.
Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class FilesController {

    ...

    //works
    @DeleteMapping() 
    public String delete(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        ...
        return "redirect:/files";
    }

    //works
    @PatchMapping()
    public String copy(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        ...
        return "redirect:/files";
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,Model model) {
        ...
        return "redirect:/files";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        ...
        return "show";
    }

    //doesn't work. 405 error. Method not allowed. App maps it like POST method
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public String rewrite(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model){
        ...
        return "redirect:/files/"+id;
    }
}
```

show.html:

```
<form th:action="@{/files/{x}(x=${file.getId()})}" th:method="Put" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            ...
            <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

How to add method mapping for multiple URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong. `enctype="multipart/form-data"` allows only POST method so HiddenHttpMethodFilter ignored PUT method. To fix it you may remove this form property and change mapping method argument from `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` to `@RequestParam("file") File file`